# Wordpress plugin: efficient way to store large data

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, database, mysql

I have excel file with 1000+ records. Basically it has zipcode and corresponding email addresses. I need to create a custom wordpress plugin which queries this data and sends the mail. It would be nice if I can show the data in admin area of the Wordpress.

Please suggest me Which is best way to maintain the data:

create a custom table in wordpress? or

Create a table outside of Wordpress, connect to it whenever I need to pull data?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

There're few plugins to storage it on WordPress database. I recommend you save as users.

I believe one of these plugins will help you:

https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-all-import/

https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-ultimate-csv-importer/

To send emails, you might use an Email Marketing provider, like Mailchimp. In this case you can import all the users to your mailchimp account with this plugin: 
https://wordpress.org/plugins/mailchimp-sync/

PS: You can search some more useful plugins for MailChimp or something else up here: https://wordpress.org/plugins